# How can I have credit cards without having a credit history or credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history, establishing-credit

Is your credit history/score like a criminal record? I mean is it always with you? Also, are there other ways to get credit cards besides with a bank? I want inside my credit score without having a commitment.

Comment: Are credit unions the same as banks in your opinion?

Comment: I don't think so. They serve different purposes. Don't you think so too? Policies, rates, and fees are distinguishable.

Comment: I don't know that (very generally) they serve different purposes.  Banks == Credit Unions by and large.  I was just curious if you a repelled by the system, or by the institutions.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want inside my credit score without having a commitment"*? Grammatically parses, but it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

## Is it like a criminal record?

That is an opinion.  I don't think so.  Here are some differences:

- Everybody in the US who uses credit, good or bad, has a credit report (other countries too, but I am no expert in that)
- NOT having a report can be just as harmful as having a bad report in some circumstances
- Having a good report can save you money
- Having a bad report can cost you money
- Having a bad report doesn't send you to jail (in the US)

If you use credit responsibly and take the time to make sure the reporting agencies are being accurate, a good report can benefit you.  So that isn't like a criminal record.

What is also important to know is that in the United States, a credit report is **about you**, not **for you.**  You are the product being sold.  This is, in my opinion, and unfortunate situation but it is what it is.  You will more than likely benefit for keeping a good report, even if you never use credit.

There are many credit scores that can be calculated from your report; the score is just a number used to compare and evaluate you on a common set of criteria.

## Having a credit score without commitment

If you think about it, that doesn't make sense.  The score is a reflection of how you use credit.  Having and using credit **is** a commitment.  Your are committing to the lender that you will repay them as agreed.

Your choice is who you decide to make agreements with.  I personally find the business practices of my local credit union to be more palatable than the business practices of the national bank I was with.  I chose to use credit provided by the credit union rather than by the bank.  I am careful about where I take auto loans from, and to what extent I can control it, where I take home loans from.

Since it is absolutely a commitment, you are personally responsible for making sure that you like who you are making commitments with.

Comment: Where do you get credit cards and usually which one offers the best deals?

Comment: There are sites that if you put in your spending habits, it will recommend the "best" deals.  I personally go for cash back cards and low interest rates.  "Best" depends on your goals - do you want rewards, value, social responsibility...

Answer (score 1):

For instance and to give a comparison to the US - in Austria, almost everybody gets a credit card (without a credit history (e.g. a young person) / with a bad credit history & with a good credit history).

The credit history is in the USA much more important than in Austria. In future, the way to assess a credit history will change due to analysis of social networks for instance. This can be considered in addition to traditional scoring procedures.

`Is your credit history/score like a criminal record?`

Nope.

`I mean is it always with you?`

Not really cause a criminal record will be retained on a central storage (to state it abstract) and a credit history can be calculated by private companies.

`Also, are there other ways to get credit cards besides with a bank?`

That depends on the country. In Austria, yes.